# How to convert DB2 database to Microsoft SQL database

Tags: sql-server, db2

Is it possible to convert databases from DB2 at Linux to Microsoft SQL at windows ?
and what is the correct steps ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, but often times it's not trivial.  Microsoft makes a free tool called [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for DB2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54254), which provides you a great starting point.  Again, migrations of this nature are not going to be just a click of a button, so you will need to thoroughly [read through the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/db2/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-db2-db2tosql?view=sql-server-2017) and do some trial runs before you decide/plan to migrate your production environment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the schema using 3rd party tools, [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com) is an opensource example.